# Getting attribute error in Python when trying to use the fixture at class level

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest-fixtures

I am using Selenium Python with Pytest framework and using conftest.py file where I have written a class level fixture

These are the plugins used. I am using Pycharm editor

Conftest.py file

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
 def driverObjectClass1(request):
     global driver
     sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())
     browser = option.browser
     chromeOpts = chrome_options()
     firefoxOpts = firefox_options()
     if option.headless:
         chromeOpts.add_argument("--headless")
         firefoxOpts.add_argument("--headless")
     if browser in 'firefox':
         driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefoxOpts)
     else:
         driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOpts)
     driver.maximize_window()
     driver.implicitly_wait(20)
     request.cls.driver = driver
     config = load_config()
     logFolder = log_Folder(config['clientID'])
     yield request.cls.driver, config, logFolder
     sleep(2)
     request.cls.driver.quit()
```

My class test_login.py

```
import pytest
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By  
from Pages.page_common import Common

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("driverObjectClass1")
 class TestLogin1:
      def test_valid_login(self):
         driver = self.driver
         config = self.config
         logFolder = self.logFolder
         common = Common(driver)
         try:
             url = config['URL']
             clientId = config['clientID']
             username = config['username']
             password = config['password']
             app1 = config['app']
             branch = config['branch']
             print(clientId, username, password, app1, branch)
             common.SCHXPLogin(url, clientId, username, password)
             common.change_branch(branch)
          except Exception as e:
             common.logFailure("test_valid_login", logFolder, e)
```

getting this error/warning when applying the fixture like this. How to fetch the yield objects in the class where the fixture is applied?

[image: Attribute Error]

How to resolve this issue?

When I run the test, I get the following error

```
FAILED test_cases/test_login1.py::TestLogin1::test_valid_login - AttributeError: 'TestLogin1' object has no attribute 'config'
```

I tried searching a solution but couldn't find the answer. So I decided to ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the Fixture in Conftest.py file as below. Now I can run my tests without error. But Pycharm Editor still showing the attribute reference warning. But when uploaded the code in VS code editor, there is no such warning. So could be specific to Pycharm Editor.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
 def driverObjectClass1(request):
     global driver
     sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())
     browser = option.browser
     chromeOpts = chrome_options()
     firefoxOpts = firefox_options()
     if option.headless:
         chromeOpts.add_argument("--headless")
         firefoxOpts.add_argument("--headless")
     if browser in 'firefox':
         driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefoxOpts)
     else:
         driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOpts)
     driver.maximize_window()
     driver.implicitly_wait(20)
     request.cls.driver = driver
     config = load_config()
     logFolder = log_Folder(config['clientID'])
     request.cls.config = config
     request.cls.logFolder = logFolder
     yield request.cls.driver, request.cls.config, request.cls.logFolder
     sleep(2)
     request.cls.driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error suggests that `driver`, `config`, and `logFolder` are not being properly set in the TestLogin1 class instance when using the `driverObjectClass1` fixture. You could add these attributes explicitly to `driverObjectClass1` as in the following:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def driverObjectClass1(request):
    global driver
    sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())
    browser = option.browser
    chromeOpts = chrome_options()
    firefoxOpts = firefox_options()
    if option.headless:
        chromeOpts.add_argument("--headless")
        firefoxOpts.add_argument("--headless")
    if browser in 'firefox':
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefoxOpts)
    else:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOpts)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)

    config = load_config()
    logFolder = log_Folder(config['clientID'])

    # explicitly setting attributes
    setattr(request.cls, 'driver', driver)
    setattr(request.cls, 'config', config)
    setattr(request.cls, 'logFolder', logFolder)

    sleep(2)
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks @samsupertaco, but it's not helping